# Call a function saved to a variable that has an event handler attached to it

Tags: javascript, function, variables, onclicklistener

Hi I am currently trying to call a function that is saved to a variable, but also has an event handler on it.

```
col.onclick = function(e){

}
```

I have not been able to find how to call this kind of set up, and was wondering if it's possible at all, and if it can be done without using jquery.

Help would be nice, thanks in advance.

http://pastebin.com/JJYQeZDG //Code that is the root of the problem.

This code is for a game of checkers, for context.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this function is nested within another function as it currently relies on the local variables of said function.

Comment: could you provide the code that is not working? hard to take a guess on how you are calling it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JJYQeZDG  here is the function that is giving me problems //This is for a game of checkers, for context.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `()` like any other function.

Based on your comments, it looks like you may also have a scoping issue.

I would recommend refactoring your code so your `onclick` function can be accessed without needed the `col` object:

```
var onclick = function(e) {
    // note: you will only have "e" if this is invoked as an event callback
};

// later when defining col
col.onclick = onclick;

// ...and later when you want to directly invoke onclick
onclick();
```

Comment: I have tried this however, in chrome console in says that it does not exist.  Which either means I have done something in correct in my code, or that there is some other way to call it.